# How to keep the view from snapping to another location when exiting camera view?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

After placing camera, when one orbits with <kbd>MMB</kbd> the view snaps to another place (wherever it was before I entered camera view) which makes one disoriented (see image, notice the selected object and viewer location). Are there any settings in Blender that can change this?

[image]
location before orbit command

[image]
location after orbit command

Answer (score 1):

Disable the Auto-Depth option in User Preferences > Interface.

[image]

There will be still a small jump in the transition but not that big.
Also making your scene larger will help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can seamlessly transition between the camera view and the perspective camera. By pressing <kbd>Num 0</kbd> you can toggle between the camera view and the last perspective view. This is a fast transition however. This will give you a slight idea as to where the two cameras are in relation to each other.

I myself don't find this too useful though. What I would do to have a better navigate your scene is to enable *Rotate Around Selection* under interface in the blender user preferences. This will keep the selected object in the same screen space when rotating in perspective view.

[image]